# Is it possible to use Ajax to call php script that has another Ajax within?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a checkbox that whenever it is checked it calls another php script using Ajax, now on the php script I got 3 text boxes with a button, and whenever the Button is pressed, Ajax will be preformed to call another php script. all of that are preformed in the same page!, it is just like this

PHP -> Ajax -> PHP -> Ajax -> PHP

Is it possible, or too much to process?!

my first Ajax is:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
        function load(cb, pos)
        {
            if (cb.checked == false)
            {
                document.getElementById(pos).innerHTML="";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            else
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                    document.getElementById(pos).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }

                xmlhttp.open('GET', "trying.inc.php?pass='true'", true);
                xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```

The second Ajax that is in "Tring.inc.php":

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
    function check()
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                document.getElementById('adiv').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }

        Parameters = "OldPass="+document.getElementById('OldPass').value+"&newPass="+document.getElementById('newPass').value+"&Confirm="+document.getElementById('ConfirmPass').value;

        xmlhttp.open('POST', 'Trying2.inc.php', true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader ('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlhttp.send(Parameters);
    }
</script>
```

that calls "Trying2.inc.php".

now when I am at "trying.inc.php" page, Ajax works in calling "trying2.inc.php", but from the main page I can call "trying.inc.php" however, "trying.inc.php" can't call "trying2.inc.php", I hope it is clear because I don't know how to explain it more. If it is possible what can I do to achieve it, please support it with code. Im doing this for learning purposes please don't be harsh on me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better to use nested ajax script than this.

Comment: Have you looked at your network tab on the developer tool? Is there an error that's displayed? If you're seeing an error like this `Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` then you might want to try adding `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` at the very beginning of **Trying2.inc.php** file HTH.

Comment: You can't execute scripts by putting them in `.innerHTML`. The only way to load scripts dynamically is by creating `script` nodes explicitly.

Comment: Yes, you can. To narrow down the problem : does the javascript on the page trying.inc.php execute ? Did you try with alert ('test') ?

Comment: nested ajax?! Im still new at this can you give me example or link? Thanks for reply

Comment: @LorenzMeyer ya it did execute

Comment: If you use jQuery's `.load()` method, it scans the response for `<script>` elements and does the necessary work to execute them.

Comment: @johnnyq Origin headers are useful with cross site ajax. Nothing here indicates that more than one domain is used.

Comment: @JohnnyQ no Origin error displayed

Comment: If 'adiv' is on the page trying php, your code does not work because the javascript executes before the html is injected into the dom.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer ya 'adiv' is in trying.inc.php indeed, ah is there any way to fix it?!

Comment: You should really think about using a framework like jquery or mootools. Like this you are sure not to have cross browser issues. Anyway, you should put your ajax call into a function.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer you beat me to it! that should work for cross site ajax only. By the way why not just do callbacks?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer thanks I'll consider doing that

Comment: @OsamaEspil I was wrong with "If 'adiv' is on the page trying php, your code does not work because..."

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jquery, you could use bind/live on the elements newely added to the dom, thus you must be able to do this.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to give an example/link to what you are referring to.

Comment: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.in/2010/08/bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-function.html?m=1